# Using Ajax To Populate A Select Box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Ok, this is my very first attempt at Ajax and its driving me insane as I really cant get my head round it. What im trying to do is populate the first box with the customers from the database, and then use the customerID to select all the vehicleID's from the database using the select.php script.
What is happening is the customers box is getting selected but when the select a customer nothing happens.

This is my Test.php file :

```
<?php include 'connectmysqli.php'; ?>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Select test</title>
        <script src="./js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $$('#customer')
                .on('change', function () {
                    $.getJSON('select.php', { customerId: $(this)
                            .val() }, function (data) {

                        var options = '';
                        for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                            options += '<option value="' + data[x][
                                    'id'] + '">' + data[x]['reg'] +
                                '</option>';
                        }
                        $('#vehicle')
                            .html(options);
                    });
                });

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <select id="customer">
                <?php
        $sql = <<<SQL
        SELECT *
        FROM `customers`
        SQL;
        if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){ die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');}
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        if ($row['bussinessname'] == ''){$name = $row['title'].' '.$name = $row['firstname'].' '.$name = $row['surname'];}else
        {$name = $row['bussinessname'];}
        echo '<option value="'.$row['customerID'].'">'.$name.'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select></p>'; ?>
        </select>
        <select id="vehicle">
                </select>
    </body>

</html>
```

This is my select.php file :

```
<?php include 'connectmysqli.php'; ?>
<?php
        $id = $_GET['customerId'];
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE customerID = ' . $id;
        $result = $db->query($sql);

        $json = array();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $json[] = array(
            'id' => $row['vehicleID'],
            'reg' => $row['reg'] // Don't you want the name?
          );
        }
        echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

I am attempting to mod this tutorial to work with the databases but so far i'm unsuccessful.
http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/

In the Chrome console I get the error :

```
Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.     miscellaneous_bindings:235
chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect
```

Comment: try `$(document).on('change', "select#customer", function(){});`

Comment: @Brewal why would that be, ?

Comment: can you check on the console to see if there is a connection being made when the item is selected

Comment: I though your `select#customer` was dynamicly added. This would have fixe the bug. But this is not the case. Do you have any error in console ?

Comment: Maybe your json syntax is wrong. Try adding your data to an array and then do `echo json_encode($data); exit();`

Comment: Your error seems to be related to a chrome extension...

Comment: This is not your script error, It is coming due to some chrome extension, disable all extensions and then check

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your customer select's change event is being assigned before the select is rendered on the page. Move the event handler into document.ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#customer').on('change', function (){
        $.getJSON('select.php', {customerId: $(this).val()}, function(data){
            var options = '';
            for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                options += '<option value="' + data[x]['id'] + '">' + data[x]['reg'] + '</option>';
            }
            $('#vehicle').html(options);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I also changed `$$('#customer')` to `$('#customer')`. Finally, fix your SQL injection vulnerability:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE customerID = ' . (int)$id;
```

Casting the ID as a int will prevent SQLi here, but you should consider using a [Prepared Statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

The error you mentioned in the question looks unrelated to your code. It looks related to a Chrome extension.

---

Not part of the problem but here is an improved version of your code that builds the vehicle options:

```
$.getJSON('select.php', {customerId: $(this).val()}, function(data){
    var vehicle = $('#vehicle');

    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
        vehicle.append(new Option(data[x].reg, data[x].id));
    }
});
```

The improvements are:

- Storing the select in a variable, so that we don't have to keep querying the DOM on each iteration of the loop
- Using `new Option(...)` and `.append()` to create the options and add them to the vehicle select. Building elements like this is better than creating raw HTML because this way, you don't have to worry about characters such as `<` and `>` in the data - which would break your HTML with the current code.
- Your data is decoded into an array of Javascript objects, so the object notation is preferred (`data[x].id`) instead of `data[x]['id']`.

Comment: You are a legend !, thanks for that, I have been wondering what the hell was going on with this ALL weekend and couldn't work it out !. THANKS !.

Comment: @IainSimpson no problem :) see my edit - added some improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Looks as if you are creating an array of JSON objects on each itteration in select.php.

Below the array is generated in PHP and then JSON encoded, which in my option is the best way to
generate JSON strings.

```
// select.php

$id = $_GET['customerId'];
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE customerID = ' . $id;
$result = $db->query($sql);

$json = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $json[] = array(
    'id' => $row['vehicleId'],
    'name' => $row['vehicleId'] // Don't you want the name?
  );
}
echo json_encode($json);

// Test.php

$('#customer').on('change', function (){
  $.getJSON('select.php', {customerId: $(this).val()}, function(data){

    var options = '';
    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
      options += '<option value="' + data[x]['id'] + '">' + data[x]['name'] + '</option>';
    }
    $('#vehicle').html(options);
  });
});
```

Comment: That's vulnerable to SQL injection beware

Comment: @andy Thanks. I was just, for simplicity sake, trying to answer the op's question. However, it is a valid point.

Comment: Iv edited my question with the new code, but its still not working ?.

Comment: @IainSimpson Did you change `Test.php`?

Comment: Yes, I updated them both as they are above ^^, I edited my question with the new code

Comment: @IainSimpson can you change it with my new edit and then post any error messages you get?

Comment: Im not getting any errrors with chrome console

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32577/discussion-between-alexp-and-iain-simpson)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try `live` instead of `on`. It is deprecated but I found out is more likely to work when element is not loaded.

> $$('#customer').on('change', function (){

changed to

> $('#customer').live('change', function (){