# Populating form values based on selected option from drop down list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql-server

I have a form that needs to populate based on a selected value from a drop down list.

This is my HTML/PHP:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="prodName">Product Name</label>
        <?php 
            $abc = "SELECT ItemCode, ItemName, CurrentPrice
                    FROM Table 
                    ORDER BY ItemName";
            $def = sqlsrv_query($sapconn, $abc);
        ?>
        <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="status" id="priceQuote">
            <?php while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($def, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
                <option data-tokens="<?php echo $row['ItemName']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['ItemName']; ?>"> 
                    <?php echo $row['ItemName']; ?>
                </option>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="prodCode">Product Code</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prodCode" placeholder="Product Code" value="<?php echo $row['ItemCode']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="bandA">Current Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bandA" placeholder="Current Price" value="<?php echo $row['CurrentPrice']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="newPrice">New Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newPrice" placeholder="New price">
    </div>
</div>
```

But I need to populate the value of product code and price from whichever option is selected, in the select list can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: you can used the ajax with jquery to do that.

following is the example for that.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367332/using-ajax-to-populate-a-select-box

Comment: https://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/

Comment: Thanks, I will look through them now.

Comment: Still no luck, I am really pulling my hair out with this now. Could you please help?

Comment: what you try and  post  that code and error if you faced any